# If we add stratified\acyclic replacement to the wholeness axiom, would that increase its consistency strength?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, embeddings

If we add to the wholeness axiom, the axiom of stratified\acyclic replacement, what would be the consistency state and strength of the resulting theory?

The wholeness axiom $\sf WA$, [introduced](http://pcorazza.lisco.com/papers/MVS/WholenessAxiom.pdf) by Paul Corazza, found to be [consistent with $\sf V=HOD$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9902079.pdf), is axiomatized in the first order language with signature $\{ \in , j\}$, where $j$ is a primitive total one place function symbol. An "$\in$-formula" is a formula in which $j$ doesn't occur.

$\sf WA$ is the statement that "$j$ is a non-trivial elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$ over signature $\{ \in \}$".

More explicity:

- $\exists x: j(x) \neq x$
- if $\varphi(x_1,..,x_n)$ is an $\in$-formula, then: $$ \forall x_1,.., \forall x_n \\(\varphi(x_1,..,x_n) \iff \varphi(j(x_1),..,j(x_n)))$$

Now, the theory is:

$\sf ZC + \sf Rep^\in + WA$

where $\sf Rep^\in$ is replacement scheme restricted to $\in$-formulas.

To be especially noticed that there is no restriction on $\sf Z$, so $j$ can be used in instances of Separation.

Now, stratified replacement "$\sf Rep^\equiv $" is Replacement schema restricted to stratified formulas.

[Stratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#Axioms_and_stratification) criterion is defined after Quine as in Stratified Comprehension, plus the requirement that $j(x)$ is one type higher than $x$.

[Equivalently](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.13274.pdf) $\sf Rep^\equiv$ can be formalized by the restriction of replacement schema to acyclic formulas, with an edge stipulated to occur between $x$ and $j(x)$ in the [definition of acyclic formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.14949.pdf).

The rationale beyond this is that the stratification\acyclicity criterion precludes Kunen's known proof of the critical sequence $\langle \kappa_n | n \in \omega \rangle $, defined as usual by $\kappa_0 = \kappa = \operatorname{cp}(j)$ and $\kappa_{n+1} = j(\kappa_n)$, being a set.

So, formally the question is:

> Would $\sf ZC + \sf Rep^\in + Rep^\equiv + WA$, be stronger than,  $\sf ZC + \sf Rep^\in + WA$ ?

**[After note]:** Stratified replacement proved to be inconsistent, since it does capture the critical sequence as shown in the answer by Greg Kiramyer. But, still the Acyclic variant remains viable. I initially thought it to be equivalent to the stratified one; I'm realizing now that the proof of equivalence of acyclicity with stratification is not carried for the language using $j$ with this particular specifications of stratification, so they might not be equivalent!? Therefore ***Acyclic Replacement*** might stand a chance?!

Comment: I don't think you want to insist that $j(x)$ have rank exactly one higher than $x$, since for some values of $x$, such as the critical point $\kappa_0$, the value of $j(x)$ will be far higher in the set-theoretic rank hierarchy. But also, there are many $x$s that are fixed by $j$, with $j(x)=x$. Indeed, the definition of the fixed point requires one to refer to these instances, but this is not possible with a $j$-stratified formula.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, No, not "rank", I meant "type" after Quine as in NF, this is metatheoretic assignment over variables in a formula of the language. $j(x)$ this is a term symbol, this receives one type higher index (than that of $x$) when stratifying the formula, so you cannot have $j(x) = x $ for example, but you can have $x \in j(x)$, the acyclic version is harsher syntactically speaking, but it turns to be equivalent with stratification over weak axioms.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the main idea behind Quine's type stratification is a proxy for set-theoretic rank. This is why when saying $x\in y$ you require that the numerical type (or rank, whatever) of the symbol $x$ is less than that of $y$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, Ah! I see what you mean. To be precise Quine's type stratification is a proxy of TYPE in type theories like TST and TSTU, and this is different from the set rank concept, ranks are accumulative while types are not, actually if one is not careful and try to parallel ranks through stratification typing, then inconsistencies are expected to erupt. Yet of course there is some resemblances with ranks.

Comment: But my point is that we may want naturally to refer to objects in $j(x)$ that are higher than $x$, and so the requirement should only be that the type of $j(x)$ is higher than $x$, not exactly one higher.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, that's what I was alluding to when I mentioned inconsistencies erupting when trying to capture stratification types on formulas as proxies for ranks, with stratified theories such an endeavor would lead straight a head to inconsistencies, but anyhow perhaps in the milieu of ZFC, matters might differ, but I wanted to err on the side of caution hear, that's why I used the traditional stratification criterion by putting it exactly one type higher.

Comment: It seems frankly bizarre to me to consider a theory with *two* different Replacement schemes, one in which formulas may not involve $j$ and another one in which formulas may involve $j$ but must be stratified. You're asking whether adding the latter to the former makes the theory stronger (over zermelo+choice+wholeness). But what about adding the former to the latter? Can't you find some natural common generalization of both schemes? Also, have you tried adapting Coret's methods of proving stratified replacement to see whether they can somehow accommodate $j$?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, I agree that adding two kinds of Replacement is somehow not that nice, but it's just the beginning of an endeavor to extend the theory already suggested by Corazza. I think we may only need to add stratified replacement since we do have all sets being Cantorian, even strongly Cantorian, so I think we can recover Replacement for $\in$-formulas. However, I'm not sure. About Coret's method, I think you mean his hereditarily symmetric sets approach, unfortunately I don't have much experience with those. Although I have experience with something similar to it.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, I think with Coret's methods AC fails.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, as an exposition, it might be neater to present both replacement schemata in one schema like putting it as $\sf Rep^{ \equiv \ j}$ to mean Replacement whose only restriction is by imposing stratification on $j$-formulas , i.e. it is unleashed for $\in$-formulas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement beginning "The rationale beyond" is not quite correct. The critical sequence can be constucted by exploiting the facts that $\bigcup j(x)$ will be assigned the same number as $x$ in a stratification assignment, $\bigcup x=x$ for any limit ordinal, and $\omega$ is well ordered by proper subset relation $\subsetneq$.

Let $F(W,K,x,y)$ be the "formula":

$x∈W \land \exists f: f \text { is a function } \land \\ dom(f)=\{t \in W \mid t \subseteq x\}  \land \\ f(0)=K \land  f(x)=y\land \\ \forall t((t≠0 \land t∈ dom(f)) \to \\f(t) = \bigcup j(f(\bigcup \{s∈W \mid s\subsetneq t\}))))$

Then for all $n \in \omega $, there is a unique $y$ such that $F(\omega,\kappa,n,y)$, the $n$-th element of the critical sequence, where $\kappa$ is the critical point of $j$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I eliminated the parenthesis.

Comment: I don't see $y$ in the formula? Also why $K$ is there? Do you intend $y=f(x)$, if so, then this needs to be added to your formula. Can you clarify the rule of $K$?

Comment: Yes, f(x)=y, but I do not know how to add it to your edit. In the last sentence, K is replaced by , the critical point.

Comment: Good answer!!! The important note here is that your formula though stratified as I defined, yet it is NOT acyclic. I thought those are equivalent, but now I see that they may not be so. Do you have an acyclic variant of this formula?

Comment: @Zuhair: If you change {∈∣⊆} to {u∈∣u⊆}, is it still not acyclic? I am too lazy to check.

Comment: Yes! It's heavily cyclic. You have $t$ connected to itself through $f$ thrice, one through the union set, one through $j$, and one through $dom(f)$. Also, $x$ connected to itself through $f$.

Comment: I wonder what happens if we alter the stratification criterion as to set $j(x)$ to be one type ***lower*** than $x$?

Comment: @Zuhair:if in a stratification assignment j(x) is assigned the number one less than the number assigned to x, one can do a similar thing. One can show that the sequence x exists where x is defined by x1=V, and x(n+1) is the power set of j(x(n)) . Then there is an ordinal λ, such that Vλ=U{xn| n∈}. λ is the sup of the critical sequence.